# Comparator and Comparable negative scenarios in java

Tags: java, hibernate, web-services, collections

I am implementing web services using java . 
In this implementation there are following steps

1) using hibernate fetch value in to database .

2) fetch value store in to class bean list type

```
List<IdentityDocArchive> resultList = q.getResultList();
```

3) Then i do sorting last update date

```
 Collections.sort(identityDocList, new Comparator<IdentityDocArchive>() {
            DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
            @Override
            public int compare(IdentityDocArchive o1, IdentityDocArchive o2) {
            try {
                  return f.parse(o2.getLastUpdtDt().toString()).compareTo(f.parse(o1.getLastUpdtDt().toString()));
              } catch (ParseException e) {
                  LOGGER.warning("Failed To Parsing string to date ".concat(e.getMessage()));
                  throw new IllegalArgumentException(e);
              }
            }
        });
```

4) Now this list value store in to another list

My Question is that is the right way to implement if not what is better approach .

Comment: `java.util.Date`s are `Comparable`, so the date-parsing part seems unnecessary.

Comment: Why don't you sort in the query?

Comment: Assuming `getLastUpdtDt()` returns a `Date`.

Comment: @mick actually last update date is DATE type field in to database . And when see in response then show with time and for entity is used @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
private java.util.Date lastupdate;

Comment: @mick it is working on my live project but just understand better aproach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use Hibernate, so you should also use hibernate/JPA to sort your data. Either via [named query](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/NamedQuery.html) `order by ...` or via [`CriteriaQuery.orderBy(...)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/criteria/CriteriaQuery.html).
You may also want to check out the [Java EE persistence tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partpersist.htm) for that.

You can also sort it by *hand* using `Collections.sort`, but then you are doing the database's intended job. (Disclaimer: you should of course set up your database accordingly: indexes, etc.)

Comment: But when it is store in to list my be it indexing goes to change

Comment: sorry... could you please rephrase your comment?

Comment: after sorting to be value store in to list may be changes . it not show the value sorting order

Comment: if the values change, shouldn't the database values change too? what do you do if you have millions of data entries and are currently working with a window of 20 entries? Do you really want to sort only those 20?

Comment: Roland it is real time scenario . So i am not not talking of number of record. i achieved this thing but i know what is better approach to making list to be sort or database to be order by

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to sort the data in the DB, and if none of the objects in the list and none of the "last updated date" attributes can be `null`, you could just implement your `Comparator` like this for descending order:

```
Collections.sort(identityDocList, new Comparator<IdentityDocArchive>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(IdentityDocArchive o1, 
                              IdentityDocArchive o2) {                               
                return o2.getLastUpdtDt().compareTo(o1.getLastUpdtDt());
            }
        });
```

This solution should be faster than your original one because it avoids redundant date parsing.

Regarding whether sorting in the DB or sorting in memory is better, it *depends*. In some cases, Hibernate could generate an `ORDER BY` clause in the query that would hurt overall performance, making in-memory sorting faster. Probably in most cases the performance of both alternatives is quite similar. But you need to try it out yourself.